# Maintain cart for a week in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, configuration, session

I am building a Magento 2 store. The Cart is saved for one hour only, it get deleted after one hour of inactivity. Is there any setting on Magento that allow a longer (may be a week or so) cart session time. Or some coding changes are need to archive this?

Comment: Everything enabled but still facing cart expiry issue for guest checkout, any idea?
My magento version is 2.1.15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it from admin configuration.

> Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Customers >> Persistent Shopping
>   Cart >> General Options >> Enable Persistence.

set it as **Yes**.

Comment: Quote Lifetime  set to 30 Days but it still get empty in 1hour?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

To update **Quote Lifetime**, Go to:

> Admin > Store > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart > Quote Lifetime

To Enable Persistent Cart *(A persistent shopping cart keeps track of unpurchased items left in the cart, and saves the information for the customer’s next visit.)*, Go to:

> Admin > Store > Configuration > Customers > Persistent Shopping Cart > General Options > Enable Persistence

Set **Yes**

This 2 setting Enable us to manage cart better and reduce cart abandonment rate.

Answer (score 0):

This change needs to be made via php.ini as per the Magento documents there is currently no setting that will extend the session life of the cart.

Within php.ini you need to modify `session.gc_maxlifetime` restart php and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure below setting to YES,

> Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Customers >> Persistent Shopping
>   Cart >> General Options >> Enable Persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Customers >> Persistent Shopping Cart >> General Options >> Enable Persistence. - **set to yes and time set to 1 day**

Quote timeout is also set to 1 day

Do we need to do server level changes as given in the comment
session.gc_maxlifetime ?

Everything is enabled for cart but cart is emptied for guest after 1 hr Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

To make this fully working there's a couple of steps you need to take / check:

1. Enable persistent shopping cart: Admin > Store > Configuration > Customers > Persistent Shopping Cart > General Options > Enable Persistence.
2. Set persistence lifetime: Admin > Store > Configuration > Customers > Persistent Shopping Cart > General Options > Persistence Lifetime (seconds).
3. Update cookie lifetime: Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings > Cookie Lifetime.
4. Make sure setting session.gc_maxlifetime on server is not shorter than desired lifetime.